# Setting color for specific value in Matplotlib imshow

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Suppose that i'm plotting the following numpy array of data on a simple matplotlib heatmap using `imshow`; there are some cases where the value will be `0.0`. Is there any way to set a specif color for the cell where that value will be shown? For example, when the value is 0, the color for that cell must be black

```
a = np.array([[0.8, 2.4, 2.5, 3.9, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0],
              [2.4, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.7, 0.0, 0.0],
              [1.1, 2.4, 0.8, 4.3, 1.9, 4.4, 0.0],
              [0.6, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.7, 1.7, 0.6, 2.6, 2.2, 6.2, 0.0],
              [0, 1.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.2, 5.1],
              [0.1, 2.0, 0.0, 1.4, 0.0, 1.9, 6.3]])   

Map = ax.imshow(a, interpolation='none', cmap='coolwarm')
```

Comment: Do you have a specific accuracy of the data, e.g. 2 decimal places?

Comment: No, it needs to be black (or any other color) only when the value is exactly zero

Comment: @JayK23 Can you just apply a cmap that has black for low values (i.e 0.0)?

Comment: @JayK23, will there be always only values >= 0?

Comment: Not always; yes, i can apply a color map that has black for low values, but i'm afraid it will mess up with the styling of the heatmap overall

Comment: Is this what you would want your heatmap to look [like](https://imgur.com/FnSR4X1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the perfect solution, but definitely a simple one. If it is only for the purpose of creating an image you can modify the original data (or a copy of it) and replace `0.0` with `NaN`. Then you can use `set_bad` to get the desired output.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.8, 2.4, -2.5, 3.9, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0],
              [2.4, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.7, 0.0, 0.0],
              [-1.1, 2.4, 0.8, 4.3, 1.9, 4.4, 0.0],
              [0.6, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.7, 1.7, -0.6, 2.6, 2.2, 6.2, 0.0],
              [0, 1.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.2, 5.1],
              [0.1, 2.0, 0.0, 1.4, 0.0, 1.9, 6.3]])   

c_map = cm.get_cmap('rainbow')
c_map.set_bad('k')
b = a.copy()
b[b==0] = np.nan
fig = plt.imshow(b, interpolation='none', cmap=c_map)
plt.colorbar(fig)
```

Comment: This is definitely a good way to go. Thank you! Last question: does the color need to be black or can it be customized and set, for example, to #ff3d3d?

Comment: You should be able to set any color you need like this: c_map.set_bad("#ff3d3d")